# Css Rem difference to Em

Tags: html, css

In my app/website i frequently use `em` and `rem` i however today found declaring an element with the same measurement i.e, height with `rem` and `em` they both gave different displays .Whats the big  difference in the 2 ? When and when-not to use one over the other ?

Comment: See the second answer of the dupe.

Comment: @PraveenKumar do not mark questions as duplicates of questions that do not have an accepted answer. You can't say: your question already has an answer at this unanswered question. Or maybe you can, but you should not.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Er... If the OP sees that and says if that's not solved, I will immediately open it up. Coz this looks like a generic question.

Comment: I think setting as duplicate of unanswered is wrong, but I also think you, as a gold `css` user, should have the ability to accept answers in this tag if owner does not, at least after some inactivity period. I'll post it on `meta`.